# Hibernate validation issue for blob sql type

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hsqldb, liquibase

I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in PUBLIC.PUBLIC.ALL_TYPES_ENTITIES for column blob1. Found: varbinary, expected: blob(255)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:383)
```

I'm creating table using liquibase:

```
        <column name="blob1" type="BLOB">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
```

The java entity has a field:

```
private byte[] blob1;
...
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob
@Column(name = "blob1")
public byte[] getBlob1() {
    return blob1;
}
```

I'm using hsqldb 2.2.9 as a database and Hibernate 3.5.0-Final as a JPA provider. Hibernate dialect for hsqldb is:

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
```

When liquibase generates a table, the liquibase HsqlTypeConverter should use VARBINARY as sql type.
WHen Hibernate validate scheme it thinks that type is blob(255), compares it with VARBINARY and throws exception.

Here is code that validates the table:

```
public void validateColumns(Dialect dialect, Mapping mapping, TableMetadata tableInfo) {
    Iterator iter = getColumnIterator();
    while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
        Column col = (Column) iter.next();

        ColumnMetadata columnInfo = tableInfo.getColumnMetadata( col.getName() );

        if ( columnInfo == null ) {
            throw new HibernateException( "Missing column: " + col.getName() + " in " + Table.qualify( tableInfo.getCatalog(), tableInfo.getSchema(), tableInfo.getName()));
        }
        else {
            final boolean typesMatch = col.getSqlType( dialect, mapping ).toLowerCase()
                    .startsWith( columnInfo.getTypeName().toLowerCase() )
                    || columnInfo.getTypeCode() == col.getSqlTypeCode( mapping );
            if ( !typesMatch ) {
                throw new HibernateException(
...
```

In debugger I can see when exception is thrown, that `col.sqlType = blob(255)`, `columnInfo.typeName = VARBINARY`. For some reason when `col.getSqlType( dialect, mapping )` is invoked to init col.sqlType, it gets blob(255). 
I suppose that I should update hsqldb dialect in the hibernate configuration. But not sure.
Don't know what should I do to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquibase does not use sql BLOB type for blobs which become available in hsqldb since 2.0 version. 
In hsqldb 1.8.X, the sql type that was used for blob was: varbinary.
In order to fix the problem, i've updated the hsqldb dialect used in hibernate:

```
public class HSQL_1_8_X_Dialect extends HSQLDialect {

    public HSQL_1_8_X_Dialect() {
        super();

        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "varbinary");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "varchar");
    }
}

<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.savdev.datasource.dialect.HSQL_1_8_X_Dialect"/>
```

It resolved the problem. Also, I suppose liquibase should either update the current `HsqlTypeConverter` or add the new one that supports hsqldb 2.X version.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `255` in your validation query because it is default value for `length` property of `@Column` annotation.

As HSQLDB supports both `VARBINARY` and `BLOB` [SQL types](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_binary_types), apparently Hibernate uses `BLOB` as the default SQL mapping for `byte[]` columns.

You can explicitly tell Hibernate to use `VARBINARY` by specifying `columnDefinition` property of `@Column`:

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob
@Column(name = "blob1", columnDefinition = "VARBINARY")
public byte[] getBlob1() {
    return blob1;
}
```

Note, that column definitions may be changed by explicit specifying of its length, as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944896/655756), but usually it is related with `String` columns.

Comment: but if I change later hsqldb to, for instance ms sql server, that supports blob as VARBINARY(MAX), than I'll have to change the Column attibute. Can I do anything with this issue? I don't think that model updating is the best option when change database server.

Comment: The thing is, that you are creating DB with `liquibase`, but validating with `Hibernate`. In this case you either have to make sure, that `liquibase` creates type, which Hibernate is expecting, or vice versa - make sure, that Hibernates is expecting the type, which is created by liquibase. For creating everything as DB-platform independent, I would allow Hibernate to create all tables/fields by itself (i.e. `hbm2ddl=update`).

Comment: then maybe you can tell me how to make liquibase create table so it would be validated by Hibernate? In a DB-platform independent way. as soon as I set columnDefinition I remove DB-platform independence at all.

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably you should try [Hibernate integration](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/hibernate.html) for Liquibase. If it doesn't help, then probably you can consider this as a bug of Liquibase-Hibernate.